# Jquery onclick hide image and remain hide after page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day everyone, I have a problem in regards hiding the image. I figure out already how to hide the image using the follow code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#optlogo").click(function(){
    $("#optlogo").hide();
  });
  $("#optenhanceseo").click(function(){
    $("#optenhanceseo").hide();
  });
});
```

my html is

```
<a href="http://localhost/dev/checkout?action=add&subscription=5"><img src="http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/logo.jpg" id="optlogo"></a>

<a href="http://localhost/dev/checkout?action=add&subscription=2"><img src="http://localhost/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/seo.jpg" id="optenhanceseo"></a>
```

Now the problem occur when I click the image and redirect to the page the image still there.

My question is:
How to remain the image hidden?

Answers are much appreciated.

Comment: You want redirection or not?????

Comment: as you are actually following the link, you would either need to use your server side language to hide the link when the page reloads, or prevent the default action of the link and ajax process the call

Comment: @Manwal I want a redirection for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are missing a `#` in the selector:

   ```
   $("#optlogo").hide();
   ```
2. You can use `cookies` to set that it should be hidden. I would recommend using [`jQuery-Cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin and use it this way:

   ```
   $.cookie('logohide', true);
   ```

   And so, every time when the page loads, check for this:

   ```
   if ($.cookie('logohide'))
       $("#optlogo").hide();
   ```

Also, if you do not want it to redirect, give `event.preventDefault()` in the function call:

```
$("#optlogo").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#optlogo").hide();
});
```

Comment: Im going to try this as the only idea I have in mind is to use cookies too.

Comment: @PHwpGUY Also you can use server sessions to set the same. If you know how to use `session_start()` and `$_SESSION` you will be able to achieve this using the server side! :)

Comment: im using wordpress for this one.

Comment: Yeah, better to do it in client side rather.

Comment: Ok will do it. Thanks